# Kusto query : how to replace empty or blank values(rows) under a column with a string like 'unknown'?

Tags: kql

Hope someone can guide me here; how to replace and rename a blank or empty value under a column to a string like 'unknown, I'm basically looking for a simple line of code like:

|extend new_col = replace(@'', @'unknown', col1) or
if (isNull(country_code), "unknown", country_code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could try using `iff` or `case` as follows:

```
datatable(s:string)
[
    "hello",
    "",
    "world",
    ""
]
| project s = case(isempty(s), "unknown", s)

// or

datatable(i:int)
[
    1,
    int(null),
    2,
    int(null)
]
| project s = case(isnull(i), -99999, i)
```